# Python sklearn не работает

Tags: python, text, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Пробую по статьям с Хабра разобраться с обработкой текста в `scikit-learn`
Если брать тестовую выборку, то все отлично работает.
Но я попробовал загрузить свою базу данных и все тексты относятся к категории `'first'`. Что я делаю не так.
И сразу следующий вопрос, можно ли показать вероятность отношения текста к данному классу.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

categories = ['first', 'second', 'third']
a = load_files('db', encoding='utf-8', categories=categories)

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(a.data)

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, a.target)

docs_new = ['God is love', 'OpenGL on the GPU is fast']
X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(docs_new)
X_new_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_new_counts)

predicted = clf.predict(X_new_tfidf)

for doc, category in zip(docs_new, predicted):
    print('%r => %s' % (doc, a.target_names[category]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методом [predict_proba()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.predict_proba).

Пример:

Исходные данные:

```
In [19]: X = np.random.randint(5, size=(6, 100))

In [20]: y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

In [21]: clf = MultinomialNB()
```

обучаем модель:

```
In [22]: clf.fit(X, y)
Out[22]: MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
```

предсказываем класс:

```
In [23]: clf.predict(X[2:3])
Out[23]: array([3])
```

все классы:

```
In [24]: clf.classes_
Out[24]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

предсказываем вероятности для всех классов:

```
In [25]: clf.predict_proba(X[2:3])
Out[25]: array([[  4.69205412e-31,   9.16479809e-30,   1.00000000e+00,   2.47492746e-28,   2.13947776e-31,   2.04949820e-34]])
```